# Are there any third party tools integrated with RobotFramework for Multi Browser testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Are there any third party tools compatible with robot framework to run the tests in three different browsers. 
That means first it should run whole suite using IE
After that it should run whole suite using FF 
Then using Chrome and this should be done automatically.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

https://robotframework.org/#libraries has a nice list of good libraries for RF and among them there is a Selenium2Library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium2Library, and define the browser in a variable, you can run the same tests against multiple browsers by changing the variable on the command line:

```
$ pybot -v BROWSER=chrome my_test_suite.txt
$ pybot -v BROWSER=ff my_test_suite.txt
...
```